# Thread in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, image, ffmpeg, popen

My company is working for visual effects and we set up an internal shot playback via a browser for our clients. For that we need to upload the video file to a FTP server.

I want to convert a image sequence to `mp4` and upload this file directly after the rendering will finish.

For that I use:

- one command prompt to convert
- one command prompt to get an `md5hash
- one for uploading the file

I already achieved that on my local computer, where I just chained `os.system('command')`.

After recognizing that the program freezes very long with longer image sequences I changed the script to spawn a thread using the `os.system` chain.
But on the Render Farm Server this script does not actually work.

The RenderFarm Server runs Python 2.5

There are some code examples:

```
class CopraUpload(threading.Thread):

    # initializing Thread
    # via super constructor
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)


    # return the size of the
    # created mp4 file
    #
    # @return: the file size in byte
    def _getFileSize(self):


    # creates a random id for organising
    # the server upload used as flag
    #
    # @return: a hash
    def _getHash(self):
            self.fileLoc = str(self.outputfileName + '.mp4')
            self.fileLoc = os.path.normpath(self.fileLoc)
            return str(os.path.getsize(self.fileLoc))

    # integrates the "missing" data for the xml file
    # generated post render from the mp4 file
    def _setPreviewDataToXML(self):
        self.xmlFile = str(self.outputfileName + '_copraUpload.xml')
        self.xmlFile = os.path.normpath(self.xmlFile)

        ett = ET.parse(self.xmlFile)
        root = ett.getroot()
        for child in root.getiterator('preview_size'):
            child.text = self._getFileSize()
        for child in root.getiterator('preview_md5hash'):
            child.text = self._getHash()
        ett.write(self.xmlFile)


    # create a connection to a ftp server
    # and copies the mp4 file and the xml file
    # on the server
    def _uploadToCopra(self):

        os.system(self.uploadCommand)
        #process = Popen(self.uploadCommand)


    # the main function of the program
    # called via start from a Thread Object
    def run(self):

        # the command which will be send to the commando shell
        # for further adjustments see ffmpeg help with ffmpeg.exe -h
        FinalCommand = self.ffmpegLocation + " -r "+ self.framerate + " -i " + self.inputPath + " -an -strict experimental -s hd720 -vcodec libx264 -preset slow -profile:v baseline -level 31 -refs 1 -maxrate 6M -bufsize 10M -vb 6M -threads 0 -g 8 -r " + self.framerate + " " + self.outputfileName + ".mp4 -y"
        FinalCommandList = FinalCommand.split(" ")


        # calling the program
        print "Start ffmpeg convertion"

        outInfo = os.path.normpath("C:\\Users\\sarender\\Desktop\\stdoutFFMPEG.txt")
        outError = os.path.normpath("C:\\Users\\sarender\\Desktop\\stderrFFMPEG.txt")
        stdoutFile = open(outInfo,"w")
        stderrFile = open(outError,"w")

        handle = subp.check_all(FinalCommandList,stdout = stdoutFile,stderr = stderrFile)
        handle.communicate()
        stdoutFile.close()
        stderrFile.close()
        print "Convertion from ffmpeg done"

        # fill the xml file with the missing data
        # - preview file size
        # - preview md5hash
        self._setPreviewDataToXML()
        self._uploadToCopra()
        print "---------------------------------->FINISHED------------------------------------------------------>"


    # Creates a callable Thread for the Copra Upload.
    # start is calling the run method which will start the Uploading
```

and the main start:

```
    if "$(RenderSet.writenode)" == "PREVIEW":
        print "---------------------------------->Initializing Script------------------------------------------------------>"
        process = CopraUpload()
        process.start()
```

What happens:

The script starts after the rendering and `ffmpeg` converts the image sequence and creates an `mp4`. But it stops after that. It does not print `"Conversion from ffmpeg complet"`. Just stops the script.

It actually should create the Thread converting with `ffmpeg` and wait until it finishes. After it should write some stuff in an xml file and upload both to the server.

Do I miss something? Is `subprocess` within a thread not the way to go? But I need a Thread because I can not deadlock the render management server.

Comment: Does the other server has the same path for the file as your local machine?

Comment: @user3679963 Hi Florian. I removed your signature from your question as it adds not necessary lines and it is not usual at StackOverflow. It is nice you do not hide your name, the best place is to change your user name to it and add any related information to your profile, people will appreciate. Enjoy StackOverflow

Comment: please try to respect PEP8 code rules. The functions comments come after the declaration within docstrings (starts and finishes with `'''` or `"""`). Don't use camelCase but lower case with underscores. see [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the command fails and throws an exception in `handle.communicate()`. Make sure you catch all exceptions and log them somewhere because threads have no way to pass on exceptions.

Also, you shouldn't use `FinalCommand.split(" ")` - if the file names contain spaces, this will fail in odd (and unpredictable) ways. Create a list instead pass that list to `subp`:

```
FinalCommand = [
    self.ffmpegLocation,
    "-r", self.framerate,
    "-i", self.inputPath,
    "-an",
    "-strict experimental",
    ...
]
```

Much more readable as well.